# AutoLayout not pinning subview to superview

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I'm trying to pin a subview inside of a custom `UITableViewCell` class to the left side of the cell's `contentView`. I'm adding the subview to the `contentView` inside of the `initWithStyle` method of the subclass, as well as adding constraints inside of that method. Unfortunately, I have two problems:

1. The subview is not pinning to the left edge of the `contentView` even though I'm using the following code to do so:

   ```
   [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[_animatedView]-[_aTextField][_rightImageView]|"
                                                                            options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeftToRight
                                                                            metrics:nil views:viewDictionary]];
   ```

   To me, that format string should be pinning the `_animatedView` to the left side of the `contentView`, and then appending the other subsequent views as close as possible afterwards. Instead, all three views show up together in the proper order in the middle of the `contentView`, instead of at the left edge. I'm new to using autolayout, so this might be a confusion of how the format strings work on my part.
2. **Solved**: Thanks to Guillaume's suggestion, I was able to do a little bit of testing and find out that the reason that the cell contents were wildly displaced as I scrolled through the table was that I had not overridden the `UITableViewCell` method, `prepareForReuse`. This method is called when a `UITableViewCell` is prepared to be reused to display information for another object in the `UITableView`, which incidentally happens when scrolling occurs. The solution was as simple as inserting the following code into my `UITableViewCell` subclass:

   ```
   -(void) prepareForReuse
    {
        [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    }
   ```

The other problem is that the constraints appear to not be enforced until I select a row of the TableView where the custom cells are being used. Is there a place other than `initWithStyle` I should be setting up the constraints or is this a different issue?

Update:

**CustomTableCell.m**

```
@interface ListTableCell ()
{
    NSDictionary *_viewsForConstraints;    // Used inside updateConstraints method.
    NSArray *_animatedViewSizeConstraints;
    NSArray *_centeringConstraints;
    NSArray *_horizontalConstraints;
}
@end

 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self)
    {
       // Set up the cell elements.
       self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

       self.animatedView = [[AnimatedView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
       self.animatedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
       [self.contentView addSubview:self.animatedView];

       self.aTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
       self.aTextField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
       self.aTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
       [self.contentView addSubview:self.aTextField];

       self.rightImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
       self.rightImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
       [self.contentView addSubview:self.rightImageView];

       _viewForConstraints = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_animatedView,   
       _aTextField, _rightImageView);

       // Add height/width constraints to the animated view.
       NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint =
       [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.animatedView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:0 toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1  constant:self.contentView.frame.size.height];
       NSLayoutConstraint *aspectRatioConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.animatedView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:0 toItem:self.animatedview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0 constant:0];

       _animatedViewSizeConstraints = @[heightConstraint, aspectRatioConstraint];

       // Center elements vertically.

       NSLayoutConstraint *animatedViewVerticalCenterConstraint =
       [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.animatedView
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:self.contentView
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:0.0];
        NSLayoutConstraint *aTextFieldVerticalCenterConstraint =
        [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.aTextField
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:self.contentView
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:0.0];
        NSLayoutConstraint *rightImageVerticalCenterConstraint =
        [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.rightImageView
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:self.contentView
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:0.0];

       _centeringConstraints = @[animatedViewVerticalCenterConstraint,
                                 aTextFieldVerticalCenterConstraint, rightImageVerticalCenterConstraint];

       _horizontalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[_animatedView]-[_aTextField][_rightImageView]|"
                options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeftToRight metrics:nil views:viewDictionary]];
       self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
       self.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
       self.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
       self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
       self.aTextField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

       [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
  }

-(void) updateConstraints
{
    [super updateConstraints];

    [self.contentView addConstraints:_animatedViewSizeConstraints];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:_centeringConstraints];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:_horizontalConstraints];
}
```

**TableViewController.m**

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell.
    cell.aTextField.text = @"Test Text";
    cell.aTextField.delegate = self;

    return cell;
}
```

I can confirm that `initWithStyle` is getting called because the background is always green and subviews always show up, they just show up very oddly spaced initially.

Thank you for any help with this!

Comment: Can you confirm that your `initWithStyle` is getting called? Depending upon how you instantiate the cell, different `init` methods will be called. For example, if you use cell prototypes, `initWithCoder` will be called, not `initWithStyle`. Perhaps you can show us the relevant portions of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Also, are all three of these subviews (`_animatedView`, `_aTextField` and `_rightImageView`) created programmatically? None of those are in the NIB/storyboard, right?

Comment: In addition to Rob's advice, I would highly recommend either setting a violent background colour or (preferably) using a tool such as DCIntrospect, which I have found invaluable in learning about autolayout. Often your constraints are being satisfied, but not in the way you expect - views could be a lot wider than you think, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I'll add the relevant code. And yes, I'm in the process of converting my storyboards to all code, so it's all instantiated programmatically.

Comment: Also, when running the app, pause execution after the screen is rendered and you can examine the autolayout hierarchy at the `(lldb)` prompt by typing `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]` and you can confirm actual frame coordinates with `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]`.

Answer (score 2):

You should setup your constraints in the [`updateConstraints`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW158) method. From the doc:

> Custom views that set up constraints themselves should do so by overriding this method.

That should *at least* solve your #2 issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice, Guillaume. Unfortunately, after implementing the updateConstraints method, it still has the same problem. I'll update the code in my question to take advantage of your answer... perhaps there's something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: So I did some more testing and found out that that same code works as expected when I insert a `[cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];` call at the end of `cellForIndexPath`... otherwise the position of the subviews varies wildly as you scroll through the list for the first time. I've never seen another code example manually call the `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` in the table controller, so I'm assuming there's a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Don't turn off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` of the `contentView` of your tableview.

I've run into this problem before.

Remove this line: `self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;`

Essentially, your view **is** pinning to the left edge of the `contentView` but the content view isn't the full width of the cell. You can use something like `DCIntrospect-ARC` or Reveal to see that it's the case.